# Find Minimum Number in a Sorted and Rotated Array with Duplicate elements

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I have worked on this problem for days but still, couldn't figure out a way to solve it. My solution can't solve some edge cases.
Problem:
**Given an array and sorted in ascending order, rotate the array by k elements, find the index of the minimum number of the array(first element of the original non-rotated array).For example: 

1. Give {3,4,1,3,3}, return 2.

2. Give {3,3,3,3,3}, return 0.

3. Give {1,1,4,1,1,1}, return 3.**

Without duplicates, this problem can be solved in O(logn) time using binary search, with duplicates a modified binary search can be used, worst case time complexity is O(n).
My code:

```
public int FindPivot(int[] array)
{
    var i = 0;
    var j = array.Length - 1;
    while (i < j)
    {
        var mid = i + (j - i) / 2 + 1;
        if (array[mid] < array[array.Length - 1])
        {
            j = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (array[mid] > array[array.Length - 1])
        {
            i = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            if (array[mid] == array[j])
            {
                j--;
            }
            if (array[mid] == array[i])
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return i+1;
}
```

It doesn't work if the input is {3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3}, it returns 3 while the correct answer is 2. Because at the last step is i points to index 2 and j moves from index 3 to index 2, it gets the correct element but i+1 makes the result wrong.What am I missing here?

Comment: simply by the line i+1, if the array is rotated k = 0 times (no rotation at all), will your answer gives index 0 as answer?

Comment: Also for cases that have multiple minimum element like [3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1] , what should be returned? The index of first minimum element?

Comment: @shole: In your example I'm sure it would have to be the first minimum, since otherwise it doesn't meet the "first element of the original array" condition. The only truly ambiguous case is something like [4,4,4,4], where there simply isn't enough information to distinguish the original first element.

Comment: @shole my code doesn't handle the case where k=0. But for cases like multiple minimum elements like [3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1], it returns index 3. Because the last step i=2, and j=3, and mid=3, array[mid] == array[end] && array[mid] == array[j], so j-- and then the loop ends at i=2, return i+1.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as below and it seems works for all cases.

I cannot think of any good way to handle all the corner cases, because your original code kind of mix up the concept of the algorithm without duplicate elements (divide into two sub arrays) and two-pointers algorithm when there is duplicate elements.

I would say the problem is that the `else` case which is moving the two pointers did not cover all cases, like there are chances that you will go into `else` block with `array[i] < array[mid]`

---

Therefore I just modified it using newbie's method: Add two variables to keep track the minimum element and minimum index we found. Update it whenever the pointers move to cover all the cases possible. Return the index at the end.  You cannot do something like return `i+1` as it won't handle case for `k = 0` which is no rotation at all ( `{1,2,3,4}`)

The modified code is written in C# which I guess from your sample code.

---

***PS:*** Though in average, this is faster than `O(N)` if the data is partially sorted without duplicate elements, it's worst case is still `O(N)` as you mentioned. So if I were you, I would just do a simple iteration and find the first minimum element...

Also from this [reference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-sorted-and-pivoted-array/), `O(N)` is the optimal you can reach if there are duplicate elements.

---

http://ideone.com/v3KVwu

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static int FindPivot(int[] array)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var j = array.Length - 1;
        var ans = 1<<20;
        var idx = 1<<20;

        while (i < j)
        {
            var mid = i + (j - i) / 2 + 1;
          //  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", i, mid, j));

            if (array[mid] < array[array.Length - 1])
            {
                if(array[mid] < ans || (array[mid] == ans && mid < idx)) { ans = array[mid];  idx = mid;}
                j = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (array[mid] > array[array.Length - 1])
            {
                i = mid;
            }
            else
            {

                // Here did not consider case if array[i] < mid  
                if(array[j] < ans || (array[j] == ans && j < idx)) { ans = array[j];  idx = j;}
                if(array[i] < ans || (array[i] == ans && i < idx)) { ans = array[i];  idx = i;}
                if (array[mid] == array[j])
                {
                    j--;
                }
                if (array[mid] == array[i])
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(array[j] < ans || (array[j] == ans && j < idx)) { ans = array[j];  idx = j;}
        if(array[i] < ans || (array[i] == ans && i < idx)) { ans = array[i];  idx = i;}
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum = " + ans);
        return idx;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int []a = {7,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,1,2,2,2,7,7};
        int []b = {3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3};
        int []c = {1,2,3,4};
        int []d = {4,4,4,4};
        int []e = {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3};
        int []f = {4,5,6,7,1,1,1,1};
        Console.WriteLine(FindPivot(a));
        Console.WriteLine(FindPivot(b));
        Console.WriteLine(FindPivot(c));
        Console.WriteLine(FindPivot(d));
        Console.WriteLine(FindPivot(e));
        Console.WriteLine(FindPivot(f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a more concise way (O(logn) for most cases, O(n) for the worst case) to reactor your code?

Comment: Just found a case where your modified code doesn't work. If the input array is {1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, code return 0, because idx always track the minimum.

Comment: I asked you what should be the answer if multiple minimum exists, you didnt answer. So as @ruakh mentioned, I took the first minimum as answer. So if 0 is not correct, what should be the answer?

Comment: For input {4,4,4,4}, program should return 0, this is a special case since all elements are the same. The correct answer is the first element of the original array.

Comment: And my code did give first element of the array as answer, whats wrong with it?

Comment: the answer should be the first element of the original array, not the first element of rotated array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @shole's answer, I modified the code a little bit to cover cases like {1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}.

```
    public int FindPivot(int[] nums)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var j = nums.Length - 1;
        var ans = int.MaxValue;
        var idx = int.MaxValue;

        while (i < j)
        {
            var mid = i + (j - i) / 2 + 1;

            if (nums[mid] < nums[nums.Length - 1])
            {                   
                if (nums[mid] < ans || (nums[mid] == ans && mid < idx)) { ans = nums[mid]; idx = mid; }
                j = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (nums[mid] > nums[nums.Length - 1])
            {
                i = mid;
            }
            else
            {
                if (nums[j] < ans || (nums[j] == ans && j < idx)) { ans = nums[j]; idx = j; }
                if (nums[mid] == nums[j])
                {
                    j--;
                }
                if (nums[mid] == nums[i])
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Deal with cases like {1,1,1,1,1}
        if (nums[i] == nums[nums.Length - 1] && nums[i] == nums[0] && i == j)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (nums[j] < ans || (nums[j] == ans && j < idx)) { ans = nums[j]; idx = j; }
        return idx;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between your "modified" version and my version on the case like {1,1,1,1,1}? Both output 0.

Comment: @shole There is no difference on {1,1,1,1,1}. Modified code is meant to cover case {1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}. Your code keeps updating idx with pointer i, which makes idx 0 in this case. Also in your comment "// Here did not consider case if array[i] < mid", I think this case will never happen because end -> start -> mid is a ascending sequence (not strictly increase, could be equal).